# Error for JS OOP beginner training

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm new in programming and I'm learning JavaScript OOP, trying to make a game with tanks. I have some code but it doesn't work properly and I need some help to understand how it works. Please check it and tell me how to solve the problem because I want to add a few more kinds of tanks but before that I need to fix the code.

```
var Tank = (function () {
    function Tank(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    Tank.prototype.getWeight = function () { return this._weight; }
    Tank.prototype.getName = function () { return this._name; }

    return Tank;
}());



var SmallTank = (function () {
    this.prototype = Object.create(Tank.prototype);

    function SmallTank(name) {
        Tank.apply(this._name);
    }

    SmallTank.prototype._weight = 2;

    return SmallTank;
}());

var myTank = new SmallTank("Aleks Tank");

console.log(myTank.getWeight());
```

Comment: "tell me how to resolve the problem" - what's the problem?

Comment: `this` in selfexecuted function reference to global object - in this case - _window_, so `this.prototype` is equals `window.prototype`

Comment: the problem is the this.prototype = Object create; line. Think, what is 'this' refering to? What is the current SCOPE? the this refers to the IIFE.

Comment: I expect to see the wight in the console, instead of that I have only: undefined is not a function

Comment: what I have to write instead of this ? or maybe I have to delete that line ?

Comment: SmallTank.prototype = Object.create(Tank.prototype);           something like this ?

Comment: The problem is resolved. Thank you to all of you !

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help you understand about inheritance, prototype, constructor functions and mix ins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're just trying to do some kind of inheritance; typically you do this by assigning a parent instance to the prototype of the child.

I think you will want something like this:

```
var SmallTank = (function () {
  function SmallTank(name) {
      Tank.call(this, name);
      this._weight = 2;
  }
  SmallTank.prototype = new Tank();

  return SmallTank;
}());
```

Alternatively you can assign `Object.create(Tank.prototype)`.

Comment: Big Thanks to you, I just have the name in the console too :) thank you again for you help

Comment: I would still prefer object.create since it leaves Tank instance specific members out off SmallTank prototype

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing what it looks like you are attempting to do, following the Mozilla guide:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

```
var Tank = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};
Tank.prototype.getName = function () { return this.name; };


var SmallTank = function (name) {
    Tank.call(this, name);
    this.weight = 2;
};
SmallTank.prototype = Object.create(Tank.prototype);
SmallTank.prototype.constructor = SmallTank;
SmallTank.prototype.getWeight = function () { return this.weight; };

var myTank = new SmallTank("Aleks Tank");
console.log(myTank.getName());
console.log(myTank.getWeight());
```